Steamed Mopping Concrete Floors Stripped Finish
I moved into a rental loft with concrete epoxy flooring and thought it was a good idea to clean the floor with my steam mop. Not so much. After going over a small area, I realized the map left behind streaks where it looks like some clear finish came right off the floor. The mop head was clean and I only used tap water.
I am wondering what my options might be for fixing this. What type of clear coat might be used here and can the affected area be spot-sealed?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated before I come clean about what happened to my landlord.


Does it seem like color was removed, or are we just seeing a sheen variation? I think test a conventional floor polish to see what it does.

Hard to say... Seems like there is simply a loss in sheen in some places but a few spots look slightly lighter than the surrounding area.  Will look into your floor polish advice. Thanks!

This appears to be similar to (mostly) commercial "floor polish" (commonly acrylic-based) products that can be applied, and dry to a hard film, but are also designed to be stripped easily when renewal is needed due to wear/aging.
"Mop and glow" (no affiliation - I don't even use it) is the one similar product that I recall being pushed at the residential market, but for a "loft with concrete floor" I'd expect a commercial/janitorial product was used.
Stripping is usually via a hot alkaline cleaner (e.g. ammonia and hot water) but steam alone may be enough to at least damage the surface film, evidently.
